# why doesn't my example gin app throw an error that goapi/mappings not found?

Tags: go, go-gin

I am learning Go and go-gin. I am trying to get a simple todo app working from a tutorial at [Gin Go TODO tutoral](https://medium.com/@ekosuprastyo15/gin-gonic-mysql-golang-example-9185f202e968).

I followed the tut step by step, mod init at root directory, installed gin, bur when I executed

```
  go build main.go
```

I received the following error.

```
  main.go:3:2: package goapi/mappings is not in GOROOT 
  (/usr/local/go/src/goapi/mappings)
```

Here is main.go

```
    package main
    import (
        "goapi/mappings"
        _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    )
    func main() {
        mappings.CreateUrlMappings()
        // Listen and server on 0.0.0.0:8080
        mappings.Router.Run(":8080")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the example shows code for multiple files, some of them in `package mappings`. You should recreate the whole example (multiple files) in a directory and run `go build`. The full source seems to be here: https://github.com/eccosuprastyo/go/tree/master/gin-login

---

You say you did `go mod init`, but **unfortunately this example doesn't use modules**, and seems to assume the example is in directory `goapi`. So you may need to set your `GOPATH` accordingly.

Instead of fighting with that example, I would personally recommend looking at the [official examples repo](https://github.com/gin-gonic/examples) - it's a proper Go module and has [instructions for building](https://gin-gonic.com/docs/examples/).

For example, if I clone the official examples and run the basic one:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:gin-gonic/examples.git
$ cd examples
$ go run basic/main.go
...
... // logging
...
```

In a separate terminal:

```
$ curl localhost:8080/ping
pong
```

Worked out of the box in less than a minute. The official Gin examples use modules (have a `go.mod`) so all the dependencies/installs are handled seamlessly.

Comment: I cloned the project and this is what results now cannot find module providing package github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql: working directory is not part of a module
main.go:4:2: package goapi/mappings is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/goapi/mappings)

Comment: @uberdave: I do recommend you start with one of the simpler *official* Gin examples and work from there. Otherwise ask the author of that blog post how they run their code.

Comment: the author did not post my question on her site, so I posted the issue on github. i'll do as you suggest and have a look at the official examples.

Comment: @uberdave: added more instructions on cloning/running official example